# how to find the right version constraint in composer-php for repo in github?

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install package [Payum/PayumBundle](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle.git),I add

```
"require-dev": {
    "payum/payum-bundle": "1.0.0-BETA2"
  }
```

to indicate I also need to download dev version.

this gives me an error:

```
 Problem 1
- The requested package payum/payumbundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

how do we find the right version constraint from git tag ,branches?
what I  tried :
2. tried the version constraint following

```
 1.0.*@beta , 1.0.0 , 1.0.*@beta ,1.0.*@dev,1.0.0@beta
```

the result is still the same

the latest tag for this project is
    1.0.0-BETA2

what is the correct version constraint for this? this [post](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version) explains what a version constraint can be , but it doesn't explain how to find the right version constraint from git tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way how to get proper version name, is go to [package detail on packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/payum/payum-bundle-sandbox).

There you'll find out there are no BETA tags available. It might be caused by not triggering autoupdate by Github.

You can see, the last dev version is: `1.0.x-dev`

So this command would normally do the trick:

```
composer require payum/payum-bundle:1.0.x-dev
```

But this package depends on another dev package, so you need to mention them both in your `composer.json`. Like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "payum/payum-bundle": "1.0.x-dev",
        "payum/core": "1.0.x-dev"
    }
}
```

And run:

```
composer update
```

That's all :). Verified!

Comment: Your knowledge  is  invaluable for me, this  solved my month long  headache, thank you very much.

Comment: Wow, that's very kind to hear!

I got stuck with similar issue few years ago, so I already enjoyed these headaches so I could gain this knowledge ;).

Comment: Haha , enjoy  coding;)